# Подставить элемент одного ассоциативного массива в другой с сохранением всех ключей

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Необходимо из одного массива подставить элемент в другой ассоциативный многомерный массив. Глубина массива не ограничена, могут быть разные уровни вложенности. Ассоциативным массивом называю тот, у которого ключи не являются цифрами.
Например,

Array1:

```
[
   options => [
      opt1 => [
         param1 => [1,2,3,4,5],
         param3 => "param3"
      ]
   ],
   styles => "style"
]
```

Array2:

```
[
   options => [
      opt1 => [
         param1 => [1,2,3,4,5],
         param2 => "param2"
      ],
      opt2 => [
         param1 => [1,2,3,4,5]
      ]
   ],
   styles => "style"
]
```

Result:

```
    [
       options => [
          opt1 => [
             param1 => [1,2,3,4,5],
             param2 => "param2",
             param3 => "param3"
          ],
          opt2 => [
             param1 => [1,2,3,4,5]
          ]
       ],
       styles => "style"
    ]
```

Исходя из примера: подставить в Array1 элементы Array2, чтобы элементы Array2 подставлялись на нужное место. Т.е. `array2[options][opt1][param2] = array1[options][opt1][param2]`, при этом не перетерся `array1[options][opt1][param3]`.

Буду очень вам благодарен.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php ???

Comment: @ArchDemon благодарю сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ArchDemon да, благодарю за ваш вариант. Почти полностью подходит, сейчас буду решать проблему с тем, что обычные массивы дозаписывает вместо того, чтобы заменять